# Is there a way to reference specific code

Tags: r

I have a sample dataframe below df.

```
    df
     ColA       ColB      ColC
      A           B         2
      D           B         3
      D           A         4
```

To get values in ColA, we can use df$ColA. But can we not reference here. For example

```
    sa <- names(Filter(is.factor,df))
    sa 
    sa
   [1] "ColA" "ColB"
```

If I use the below code, I am not getting elements of ColA. Should be getting right? Or is there way to do this

```
     df$sa[1]
```

Comment: You want to use `[[`, not `$`: `df[[sa]][1]`

Comment: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds   . Getting this error

Comment: Just noticed `length(sa) > 1L`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el

Answer (score 0):

We can't reference columns with `$` when having `sa` as character vector. We can do

```
df[sa[1]]

#  ColA
#1    A
#2    D
#3    D
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(sa[1])
```